# If the translation of a vector remains orthogonal to a translation of a space?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W$ a subset of it which is not necessarily a vector space. $v$ is orthogonal to $W$.

> Given some vector $u$ one can guarantee that $v+u$ is still orthogonal to $W+u$?

Observe that $W+u=\{w+u| \ w\in W\}.$

By drawing the figure it seems yes, however I could not prove that. Any comment or answer?

Comment: What do you mean by a subspace which is not necessarily a vector space?  A subspace is a vector space by definition.

Comment: Sorry I mean subset. I correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

Consider a simple 2D example: take $v = (1,0)$, $W = \{(0,1)\}$ and $u = (1,1)$. Then $v \perp W$, but $v+u=(2,1) \not\perp \{(1,2)\}=W+u$

Answer (score 3):

What if $v=0?$. Then $v\perp W$ but $u$ not necessarily perpendicular to $u+W$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\langle v,w\rangle = 0$ for all $w\in W$.
For each $u$, $\langle u+v,u+w\rangle 
= \langle u,u\rangle +\langle u,w\rangle + \langle v,u\rangle + \langle v,w\rangle$, since the scalar product is bilinear.